# Sorting arrays, and selecting lowest numbers?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have created several arrays, containing multiple integers. Now i want the integers to be sorted, lowest first. Say for instance, i have this in an array: 6,6,1,2,4,4, i want it to be sorted: 1,2,4,4,6,6. Also, is there anyway i can make ruby recognize the 4 lowest values, and display them somehow? I have tried to mess around with .show, but since im quite new to programming i'm rather confused by the results i receive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try this?

```
a = [6,6,1,2,4,4]

p a.sort
#=> [1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6]
```

`sort` will sort in ascending order.

if you need them sorted in descending order, use `sort` with a block:

```
p a.sort {|a,b| b <=> a}
#=> [6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 1]
```

**UPDATE:** not sure how i missed the part about lowest values ...

thank you @Mladen

```
a.sort.take(4)
#=> [1, 2, 4, 4]
```

Comment: And to take 4 lowest values, one can use `a.sort.take(4)`

Comment: And is it possible in any way, to make it select all of the lowest values? Example, if i have 2 arrays with numbers, the first one contains: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4] then it would just select, 1,1,2,2. What if the arrays has [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4] - is it possible to make it save 1,1,2,2,2?

Comment: try this: `max = 2; a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4].select{|v| v <= max}`

Comment: The issues is that i need to do it for several arrays, with various numbers in it, sometimes it might not be 2 that is the 'highest', it could be any other number between 1 and 6. Any ideas how to do it like that? :-)

Comment: in an array containing numbers from 1 to 6, what are the lowest and why? do you mean any number lower than median?

Comment: btw, did you try my refactor [on your another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611211/ruby-wont-load-file-into-arrays)?

Comment: Well, basically im writing a program, that takes a file, and then calculates a score from the 4 lowest numbers (5or6 if there's more of the same value, being used as 'lowest'). The numbers could be anywhere between 1-6, and could consists of (1,1,1,2,2,2,2) or (3,4,5,5,5,6,6). In the first case you would only need the first 4 numbers, but the second example you would need the 5 (the reason i need them is to calculate a score with them) Yea i tried the refactor on my other question, worked aces thanks :-)

Comment: sorry, i do not understand why in first case it should select first 4 and on second first 5

Comment: `a.sort.reverse` for descending